# Is there a way to change the color of certain text in tmux?

Tags: bash, shell, plugins, tmux

Is there a way to change the color of certain text in tmux?

I want to do something like this.

For example,
I run the command `sqlite3 a.sqlite select * from data;`
And it print out

```
id|key|value
0|haha|yes
1|qq|no
```

And if I click on key or haha, or qq

all the text between the first | and the second | will be highlight as color red.

Can tmux achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tmux has no builtin way to do this, although it is quite a nice idea.

There may be programs you could pipe output to to do this, maybe something like colortail.